# how to create a query two or more values?

Tags: sql

I would need if I could help with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE `car` (                                     
          `car_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,      
          `car_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,                    
          `car_year` date NOT NULL,                       
          PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`)                                 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE `people` (                                                                                              
             `peo_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,                                                                    
             `peo_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,                                                                                      
             `peo_surname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,                                                                                      
             `car_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,                                                                                  
             PRIMARY KEY  (`fav_id`),                                                                                              
             KEY `FK_Favorites` (`user_id`),                                                                                       
             CONSTRAINT `FK_Favorites` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`car_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I have questions, show all cars that are more than 3 people ordered by year of car.
Thank you very much, sorry for my bad English

Comment: what do you need to do with 2 or more values?  do you need to select?

Comment: I need to select all the cars that are more than 3 people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    c.car_id
    ,c.car_year
    ,COUNT(p.peo_id)
FROM car c
INNER JOIN people p on c.card_id = p.car_id
GROUP BY    c.car_id ,c.car_year
HAVING  COUNT(p.peo_id) > 3
ORDER BY c.car_year
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find number of cars with more than three people

```
select car_id
from people
group by car_id
having count(*) > 3
```

Now, get the car details

```
select * from car
where car_id in
(
 select car_id
    from people
    group by car_id
    having count(*) > 3
)
order by car_year
```